# slocate - how to search a particular directory

Tags: file, search, locate

How can I search a particular directory using 'slocate' (locate, mlocate)? It seems that, unlike 'find', slocate does not provide an option for the directory to search in, so at this moment I just do

```
slocate file_name | grep "/home/"
```

but have a feeling that this is not the best option.

Thanks in advance for insightful comments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with slocate + directory, for example if you wanto to locate `home` directory:

```
slocate home/
```